# How do I dynamically remove these elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to remove `<li>` elements if they have been around longer than a minute. Each `<li>` contains an `<a>` element that has a `data-created-at` attribute. This `created_at` value was stored server side in a database.

When the page loads, it displays records from the databas.

```
<ul id="foobar">
  <% @foos.each do |foo| %>
    <li><%= link_to 'Foobar', '#', :'data-created-at' => foo.created_at.to_i %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

My JS is trying to compare the system's (browser, not server) time before it removes the `<li>` element:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#foobar a').each(function() {
      if(new Date().getTime() - $(this).data('created-at') >= 60000) {
        // It's been a minute
        $(this).parents('li').fadeOut()
      }
    });
  }, 10000); // 10 seconds
});
```

It's a problem, because I need JS to dynamically remove any `<li>` elements. Since `Date().getTime()` is based on the browser / system. It's a bit inconsistent if its dealing with the `created_at` value rendered from the server.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: just ask the server for the time

Comment: I thought of this. Querying the server for the time every 10 seconds. Ain't overkill?

Comment: I'm thinking of querying server time once on page load, calculating an offset and just use local (system) time from there.

Comment: Agreed with @Lilina, once you have the offset you can derive what you need.

Comment: Can't you just insert the date-created-at on the client when you load each `<li>`?

Comment: @jimw the `<li>` elements are being loaded from the backend

Comment: Right, but you can add the date-created to them when you load them? If you're removing them after a minute, I assume the server's date-created tag gives the time of the HTTP request being served, rather than some more distant 'creation' time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes @Lilina has a good approach. Insert the timestamp as a hidden input at the end of HTML document. This ensures it's loaded last. Then add a document ready handler to calculate the offset between browser time and system time (from the hidden input tag). Apply this offset to all created-at attributes.

Comment: Calculating the offset is `browser_time` minus `server_time`?